# Accessing user provided env variables in cloudfoundry in Spring Boot application

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have the following user provided env variable defined for my app hosted in cloudfoundry/pivotal webservices:

```
MY_VAR=test
```

I am trying to access like so:

`System.getProperty("MY_VAR")`

but I am getting null in return.  Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you set up your "user provided env variable defined for (your) app"?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta I add the env variable as follows.  1)Login to pivotal.io 2) click 'pivotal web services'  3) clicked my 'space' name 4) click my 'app'  name 5) click on 'env variables' tab  6) add 'user provided' env variables as a key value pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment variables and system properties are two different things. If you set an environment variable with `cf set-env my-app MY_VAR test` then you would retrieve it in Java with `System.getenv("MY_VAR")`, not with `System.getProperty`.

A better option is to take advantage of the Spring environment abstraction with features like the `@Value` annotation. As shown in the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), this allows you to specify values that get injected into your application as environment variables, system properties, static configuration, or external configuration without the application code explicitly retrieving the value.

**Note**: You'll have to restage your application for your app instances to pick up the new env var.

Comment: Thanks I'll give System.getenv("MY_VAR") a try and let you know.  Normally I like to @Value("${MY_VAR}") whenever possible but in this particular use case the class we need to access the environment variable in is not a Spring managed @Bean nor can it be made one.

Comment: @mjj1409: An additional note, you'll have to restage your application for your app instances to pick up the new env var.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility leaning on Scott Frederick's answer (sorry, I can't comment on the original post):

User provided env vars can easily be accessed in the application.yml:

```
my:
  var: ${MY_VAR}
```

You can then use the @Value-Annotation like this:

```
@Value("${my.var}")
String myVar;
```